# Artillery.io using Body url encoded form not working

Tags: load, artillery

It's worth noting that my request works in Postman.

I essentially have the following

```
scenarios:
  - name: 'Hit the Endpoint'
    flow:
      - log: "Hit the endpoint"
      - post:
          url: "/endpoint"
          headers:
            accept: application/jwt
            Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            cache-control: no-cache
          body:
            token: blah
            client_id: blah
            client_secret: blah
            token_type_hint: 'access_token'
          expect:
            - statusCode: 200
          capture:
            regexp: '[^]*'
            as: 'result'
      - log: 'result= {{result}}'
```

When I remove the body from the yaml file, the endpoint seems to be hit and sends back the correct message. When I add the body back in I get the following:

```
vusers.created_by_name.Hit the Endpoint: .................... 5
vusers.created.total: ....................................... 5
vusers.failed: .............................................. 5
errors.ERR_GOT_REQUEST_ERROR: ............................... 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Used `form` instead of `Body` as per the documentation

https://www.artillery.io/docs/guides/guides/http-reference

Comment: If the link becomes broken, then your answer will become unclear.